# Как в Laravel 5.5 передать переменную в yield шаблона-родителя?

Tags: php, laravel, php7, laravel5, blade

Предположим есть шаблон **layout.blade.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>@yield( 'page-title' )</title>
</head>
<body>
    @yield( 'content' )
</body>
</html>
```

И есть шаблон **sub.blade.php**:

```
@extends( 'layout' )
@section( 'page-title', 'СЮДА_НАДО_ПЕРЕДАТЬ_ЗНАЧЕНИЕ_ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ'  )
@section( 'content' )
    <div>
    Hello, World!
  </div>
@endsection
```

Я хочу в шаблоне **sub.blade.php** передать значение переменной для **page-title** и никак не найду правильный способ это сделать. Ниже указанная конструкция вызывает ошибку:

```
@section( 'page-title', {{ $MyPageTitle }} )
```

Как нужно это делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указывайте в `section` вторым параметром просто значение:

```
@section('page-title', $MyPageTitle)
```

Вместо:

```
@section( 'page-title', {{ $MyPageTitle }} )
```

Так же ещё бывает проблемы с названием секций через дефис, лучше тоже замените его с `page-title` на `pageTitle`.